# Bisyllabic German Verb Roots with the Stress Being on the First Syllable

Tags: german

I'm looking for German verbs with a bisyllabic root that have are stressed on their first syllable. But verbs like *ändern* or *wechseln* and also *eignen* don't count, which would be verb roots that end in *-er*, *-el* or *-en*. Compound verb roots and verb roots with a suffix don't count. Stressed separable prefixes clearly don't count either (e.g. *anfangen*).

Basically the two verbs *arbeiten* and *heiraten* seemed odd to me in that they are similar in sharing the above characteristics, but are unlike any other verb I tried to think of. Are there more verbs like those two?

Comment: *regnen*, *leugnen* and others that fit the pattern.   More exceptional: *weihnachten*.  I assume *festigen* is disqualified, but then what is a root here?  Are we sure *Arbeit* and *Heirat* were not compounds?  And the noun that was verbed to make *feiern* ends in *-er* but there is no *fei*, likewise many words ending in *-el* are from Romance languages.  True also for inherited roots like *Wasser*.  We can't use only `grep` to filter by etymology.

Comment: Yeah, but none of those verbs fall exactly in the line I drew around *arbeiten* and *heiraten* in my head when I asked the question. I should have excluded all verb roots ending in *-er*, *-el*, *-en* outright (since I don't view them as special the same way I do the two original examples), the same with compound verb roots and those with suffixes. Should I maybe reframe the question, start with *arbeiten* and *heiraten* and then explain why they seem so special, yet similar to me?

Comment: Sure, I asked what "root" means here.  But it seems circular.  From what I understand, if there were a new suffix *-at* (which in fact there sort of is, thanks to Latinisms and pseudo-Latinisms - *Plagiat*, *Laminat*, *Cervelat*...), then *heiraten* would be disqualified, despite the fact that it's etymology is totally independent!

Comment: It seems like your candidate pool is mostly nouns that 1) have two syllables, with stress on first 2) have been verbed without an additional suffix (so no *verabscheuen* 3) have an opaque etymology.

Comment: 3 will be mostly compounds or loans, but you're forcing this by insisting we all pretend that *Wasser* is not an opaque root and *shrinkwrap* is.  And loans like *Feier* and *Zettel* are just collateral damage.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with that. 1 and 2 are fine, but 3 in my opinion should be something like "no suffixes or schwa-like second syllables." I think the example sumelic gave in his answer to this question is fine and even very good if it were an organic German verb/denominalized noun. But that would up the count to only 3, which is still strangely low (like you could easily imagine there being more nouns/verbs like that before you start thinking about it).

Comment: There are plenty of languages where stress is entirely predictable, and in many of those it's simply calculable that no word qualifies.  (eg final stress like French or Armenian or penultimate stress like Spanish.)  As a nativish speaker I haven't thought about the stress of German much except to note that it definitely varies between dialects, but maybe there is a rule that native suffixes get no stress and loaned ones do, and native prefixes only get stress if they are separable (*umfahren* vs *umfahren*).

Comment: But disqualifying schwa is really arbitrary to me as a person who speaks languages with stressed schwa in roots made of consonant clusters.

Comment: Yes, there certainly are rules governing where stress falls in German nouns, one of which being that separable prefixes are always stressed and (Germanic-origin) suffixes or inseparable prefixes are not (actually I think that's pretty much it, looking at words of Germanic origin).

Comment: But it might actually be that there are only very few bisyllabic German noun roots. Other than *Arbeit* and *Heirat* there are *Armut* and *Heimat* for example (funny how they even match), but those can't be turned into verbs. I don't know how many more there are. I'd be curious to know if there is a list of such nouns somewhere and how many there are (as opposed to the verb version).

Comment: There are many bisyllabic noun roots, just not by your criteria - *Wasser*, *Regen*, *Apfel*... *Ende* and countless feminine nouns.  It's more like a rule - maybe not unique to nouns - that unstressed syllables of roots get schwa.

Comment: What do you think of *Käfig*?

Comment: There turned out to be more German noun roots of Germanic origin with more than one schwa-less syllable than I thought, some are gathered in another question I posted after this and the answers/comments there. *Käfig* does fit the criteria perfectly, though, I didn't know *käfigen* was also a verb. Still interesting how, at some point or another, all these verbs came from nouns, so I'm now going to suggest there aren't any schwa-less bisyllabic German original verb roots, period.

Comment: I assumed you would disqualify *Käfig* because *-ig* is also a suffix.

Comment: It is not in this case, at least as far as I understood.

Answer (score 3):

Using the CELEX database, you can find some verbs that match your criteria. There aren't many, and as others have already said, these are mostly deadjectival or denominal verbs on *-ig* (*ängstigen*, *bändigen*, *billigen*, *einigen*, *fertigen*, *festigen*, *huldigen*, *kräftigen*, *kreuzigen*, *kündigen*, *mäßigen*, *nächtigen*, *nötigen*, *peinigen*, *predigen*, *reinigen*, *sänftigen*, *sättigen*, *schädigen*, *steinigen*, *sündigen*, *tätigen*, *willigen*, *würdigen*, *zeitigen*, *züchtigen* ...) and denominal verbs like *antworten*, *arbeiten*, *argwöhnen*, *frühstücken*, *heiraten* (no connection to *heil*, by the way -- there's an old Germanic word for 'household', 'family' in there), *kennzeichnen*, *kiebitzen*, *langweilen*, *mutmaßen*, *ohrfeigen*, *urteilen*, *weihnachten*, *wirtschaften* and some more.

Then there's also *ehelichen* and *dolmetschen* (borrowed from a Slavic language that got it from Turkish *tilmaç*).

Comment: Thanks! This looks comprehensive, do you think I should mark it as the right answer?

Comment: That's up to you, I suppose!
I don't know how comprehensive this list really is -- as far as I know, there aren't that many ressources that include information on syllables, stress patterns and morphemes, and those that do, like CELEX, usually aren't *that* large (CELEX only includes about 50k German lemmata). So some words are probably missing, especially low-frequency words and specialised vocabulary.

Answer (score 2):

There is [batiken](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/batiken).

I think that German verb roots are mostly monosyllabic (that is, when we exclude prefixes, particles, and the first elements of compounds, and ignore the presence of second syllables that are merely "reduction syllables" like *er* or *el*). I don't know to what extent this is based on inheritance from Proto-Germanic vs. sound changes like syncope of unstressed vowels. Is it any easier to find examples of bisyllabic German verb roots with stress on the second syllable? I can't think of any right now.

All of the examples of verbs with more than one non-schwa vowel in the root seem to be denominal verbs: *arbeiten* from the noun *Arbeit* (or from its ancestor) and *heiraten* from *Heirat* (or from its ancestor). Likewise, *batiken* is from *Batik*. But I do not expect the class of verbs like this to be very large because I think German noun roots are also mostly monosyllabic.

As I mentioned in the answer to your [follow-up question about nouns](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/31490/german-noun-roots-of-germanic-origin-with-multiple-non-schwa-syllables), there may be around a hundred disyllabic noun roots in German, of which some or most might be "nativized loans". The noun *Käfig* apparently was not inherited from Proto-Germanic, but borrowed from Latin at some point during the history of German. It is clearly an older and more nativized borrowing than my example of *Batik,* but neither seems to technically be a native German root.

Comment: That's kinda exactly what I was looking for? Still kind of a cheat, though. I get the other point, but verbs ending in *-ern*, *-eln*, *-nen* show up regularly. Compound verb roots are not that special either (although still far from what the majority of German verbs resemble, e.g. *handhaben*). But *arbeiten* and *heiraten* are pretty special in that way and I guess their etymology would shed some light on why that is and that makes me curious if there is any other similar to those.

Comment: Sure, and *batiken* is a nice example, but *Batik* is a loanword, and that's what makes it look like a cheat. My intuition is also that German noun roots are mostly monosyllabic (or else bisyllabic with a schwa-like second syllable. Maybe I should be looking for bisyllabic German noun roots of Germanic origin similar to *Heirat* and *Arbeit*.

Comment: Re: your recent edit(s). There are so few that I'd be glad to find more regardless of origin. I wouldn't have expected the answer to the question of how many bisyllabic German verb roots there are to be that low, or the number of ones that didn't originally belong to another root class to be **zero** (I just thought of *fertigen*, by the way, but the same thing applies there).

Comment: @user3482545: There are a number of other verbs ending in *-igen*; I didn't look very deeply into them because  Adam Bittlingmayer already mentioned *festigen* in his first comment. I don't know whether *faulenzen* also works for you?

Comment: Yes, but those are suffixed (*fertig* is too, but at least only etymologically). I'd say *flaunzen* works perfectly. Just thought of *empören* and was happy it's even stressed on the second syllable, but actually it behaves as if the *em-* were an inseparable prefix, but prefix it is, again, only etymologically. I would've gone investigating wether any verb root unstressed in its first syllable behaves that way, but there may be just that one.

Comment: @user3482545: Well, there's a passage here about other verbs in -igen: https://books.google.com/books?id=QltAAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA128&lpg=PA128&dq=verbs-in-igen I can't really tell how to draw a distinction between it being a suffix or just an etymological suffix. For example, does *heiligen* not count because of the existence of the word *heil*?

Comment: This whole question is in my opinion pointless now anyway, unless someone finds a single original bisyllabic verb root without schwa (not in any way derived). There is a better question, which I posted here and which you saw as well. But yes, I could imagine only *fertig* being special and none of the others.

Answer (score 0):

A few more examples in addition to Cyreth's great answer:

*malochen*, *roboten* (another two words semantically close to *arbeiten*, both loans, the former from Yiddish and the latter from Czech or another Slavic language), *haushalten*, *urlauben*.

Comment: Thanks, the first example reminded me of *schmarotzen*, which I thought was a Yiddish loan, but Duden says its origin is unclear. From that I got suggested *nassauern*, which is also interesting.

Answer (score -1):

For simplicities sake you can assume "arbeit-en" and "heirat-en" are learned as derivatives from the respective nouns. Thus you can also find ... many verbs on "-ieren", e.g. "telefonieren", "persiflieren", "betonieren", "kastrieren" or "sortieren" (so much that it's a meme to attach it to any loan, e.g. "ban" > "bannieren", although "Bann, bannen" already exist and "-ieren" smacks more of French than English).

Further, with "Heirat" the root is "Rat, raten" (advice, council) with the suffix "Heil" (health, prosperity), *high* (cp "Hoch-Zeit"). So assuming the same holds for "Arbeit", the question would be, what's the root? It's obscure, tentativelly and rather grimmly linked to "orphan". "-eiten" is frequent rhyme for verbs, e.g. "weiten, reiten, schreiten, begleiten", corresponding to *-it-*, cp. respectively *weit, Weite" (far, width), *Ritt* (p.p. "rode"), "Schritt" (step, crotch), but "Geleit, leiten" (entourage, to lead), not "gleiten" (glide) and probably neither "leiden", preterite "litt-" (suffer), nor "lassen" (let), "losen" (lot), "lösen" (solve) [ok, bad example]. But this tells us nothing, really.

Comment: I'd be interested to know the etymology if *Arbeit* in detail. Still strange that there are only two *verbs* of the kind I described.

Comment: @user3482545: Wiktionary has it here https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/arbeiten

Comment: There's no *Heil* in *Heirat*, guxtu here: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Heirat#German

Comment: @jknappen, well, I did not make that up, but I do not remember where I read it years ago. Either way "Rat" is a component, just that *Gerät* etc is not what I had in mind.

Comment: Regardin "Arbeit" if you click through you'll read "Apparently linked to", "probably", "kann" etc.

Comment: At least a connection to *rabota* (via DWDS/Arbeit) and *orphan* could explain *Raben-Eltern*.